# ViewBinding with 2 possible layouts

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

I am doing the migration to view binding and I have a fragment where I use 2 different layouts depending on a variable. Basically it goes like this.

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
) = inflater.inflate(

    when (ussdType) {
        UssdType.USSD_TYPE -> R.layout.fragment_transaction
        else -> R.layout.fragment_balance 
    }, container, false
)
```

The problem is that if I refactor it to viewbinding I will need 2 types of viewbindings (FragmentTransactionBinding and FragmentBalanceBinding) so for example to use a button element.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    continue_button.setOnClickListener { onContinueAction(it) }

}
```

I don't know how to proceed since I have 2 different viewbindings

Answer (score 0):

I'm also given a project which has 2 possible layouts in a fragment.

There are only 3 ways out. (If you don't have time to read, go with the 3rd option which is the best way)

One is to continue with findViewById() or Kotlin Synthetics. But both are not a good solution.

2nd way is to use two nullable viewBinding variables and use ? To do task So the one which is not null will be executed. If you want some value out of views, then you can get either of the bindings using smart null checks (Elvis operator) ex: `val text = b1.tv.text ?: b2.tv.text`

3rd (best way) is, create another fragment for BalanceFragment and use respective binding in it. This will also help you separate out the code so you have clear separation of concerns.

Answer (score -1):

Simply create two variable that represent viewBinding

```
private lateinit var bindingTransaction: FragmentTransactionBinding
private lateinit var bindingBalance: FragmentBalanceBinding
```

and inflate one of them depend on your `ussdType`

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        return when (ussdType) {
            UssdType.USSD_TYPE -> {
                bindingTransaction = FragmentTransactionBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
                bindingTransaction.root
            }
            else -> {
                bindingBalance = FragmentBalanceBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
                bindingBalance.root
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The real problem here is that even if I just put one layout element as example it has a lot that I need to use so with this solution I will have to write 2 times the same code (1 for each layout)

Comment: so maybe you do not need 2 different layout that behave similarly?